# Send Reminder application invitation to facebook friends

Tags: facebook

Can facebook send reminder  invitation for application request? In my web application ,member have facility to send invitation to his/her facebook friend for join my application. I am using facebook multi selector to send application invitation. I want to send a reminder invitation after a one week to facebook user which haven't join my application. Can anyone tell me how can i send a reminder to facebook user for join my application? Can facebook give any facility to send reminder via multiselector or if facebook provide and other facility.

Plz give any suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about you go about it this way:

1. use the facebook API to connect the user and list his/her friend on your site with a checkbox beside each.
2. Send an invitation to the checked friends (via a dm maybe) and save the friend list in a db (you can call the table 'invites' and should include date, invitee and status). The invitation/registeration link should include a referer id to track the invitee.
3. Once the invitation is honored, GET the referer id and update the status to registered (you can denote that with 1).
4. Setup a daily cron to check for invites with not registered status that is 15 days. Resend invite to them.

Only problem is storing the user's friends has great privacy issues. If you must do it, make proper provisions in your privacy policy.

Comment: Thanks Kehers! I am using above mention invitation flow on my application, I can send reminder invitation for non facebook inviter(gmail,yahoo etc) via cron job, i want to know how i send a reminder for facebook initer? can i sent application request with graph api, means can i create a script for cron job for send reminder.